# threads and ttask delphi fmx?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, task, firemonkey

i am trying to do some processing on second thread and for that i am currently using TTask and currently coded this thing with the knowledge i gained from previous explained questions here and in other tutorials :

```
procedure Process;
var
  Task: ITask;
  sMS, pMS, pMS2: TMemoryStream;
  Bitmap1, Bitmap2, Bitmap3: TBitmap;
  sRect: TRect;
begin
  Form2.AniIndicator1.Visible := true;
  Task := TTask.Create(
    procedure
    begin
      sPdf := TDebenuPDFLibrary1613.Create;
      sPdf.UnlockKey('stackoverflow@1234');
      if sPdf.LoadFromFile(FileName, 'RAMBO@45454593') = 1 then
      begin
        sPdf.SetOrigin(1);
        sPdf.SelectRenderer(4);
        sPdf.SetPDFiumFileName('eLibUM32.dll');
        pMS := TMemoryStream.Create;
        pMS2 := TMemoryStream.Create;
        try
          sPdf.SetPageBox(2, 37, 659, 243, 152);
          sPdf.RenderPageToStream(300, 0, 5, pMS);
          Bitmap1 := TBitmap.CreateFromStream(pMS);
          sPdf.SetPageBox(2, 314, 659, 243, 152);
          sPdf.RenderPageToStream(300, 0, 5, pMS2);
          Bitmap2 := TBitmap.CreateFromStream(pMS2);
          with sRect do
          begin
            Top := 0;
            Left := 0;
            Width := Bitmap1.Width;
            Height := Bitmap1.Height;
          end;
          Bitmap3:= TBitmap.Create;
          with Bitmap3 do
          begin
            Height := Bitmap1.Height;
            Width := Bitmap1.Width * 2 + 5;
            Clear(TAlphaColors.White);
            CopyFromBitmap(Bitmap1, sRect, 0, 0);
            CopyFromBitmap(Bitmap2, sRect, sRect.Width + 5, 0);
          end;
          TThread.Queue(TTHread.CurrentThread, procedure
          begin
          Form2.AniIndicator1.Visible := False;
          Form2.Image1.Bitmap.Assign(Bitmap3);
          end);
        finally
          pMS.Free;
          pMS2.Free;
        end;
      end else
       TThread.Queue(TThread.CurrentThread,
       procedure
       begin
       ShowMessage('Password Error !');
       end);
      sPdf.Free;
    end);
  Task.Start;
end;
```

but sometimes it does not loads the bitmap into image1 of form2.
am i doing any mistakes in task or in que of thread ?

Comment: Which Delphi version? In early firemonkey implementations the bitmaps were not thread safe.

Comment: @LURD latest Delphi 10.3.2

Comment: You don't ``.Free`` your bitmaps...

Comment: Please [edit] your question title so that it is something more than mere repetition of the tags. Your title should be descriptive enough of the problem or question to be of use to future readers who are scanning a list of search results. While you're making that edit, you can also add a tag for the specific Delphi version you're using, because FMX changes very often and knowing which version you're using matters. Thanks.

Comment: When calling `TThread.Queue()`, you should usually set the 1st parameter to `nil` instead of `TThread.CurrentThread`. When a `TThread` ends, any pending `Queue`'d procedures that are associated with that `TThread` are cancelled, which you don't want to happen in this situation. The only time you should specify a `TThread` in the 1st parameter is if the `Queue`'d procedure needs to access non-static members belonging to that `TThread` which would be invalid to access if the procedure runs after the `TThread` has ended and been freed beforehand.